# Is there a way to save a process and retrieve it after a reboot?

Tags: process

I know that the best way of accomplishing similar tasks is to save intermediate results into a file and restore the state from that file. But out of curiosity, I just wonder whether there is a way to save a process and retrieve it after a reboot. That's all.

Comment: Not easily, because pointers and OS handles will be different.

Comment: In a general sense that will work for all processes, the answer is no. Even if you disabled problematic things like ASLR and snapshotted your process's entire address space, there are still going to be a ton of kernel-mode objects you need but don't have access to. Some interpreted languages do have the ability to outright save their state, and others have some amount of features built in to make it at least a little easier. What's your environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I create a dump file of my process and get the address of my variables. Then I extract all the data I need from the file.